# Google maps autocomplete restriction not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I had the following:

```js
  function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 47.371068, lng: 8.538540},
          zoom: 500,
          zoomControl: false,
          disableDefaultUI: true
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);
        document.getElementById("bottomBar").style.opacity = "0.0";


        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }
```

This works but its not restricted to 1 country only when i type in the search bar.

I tried the following:

```js
// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}};
        var searchbox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);
        document.getElementById("bottomBar").style.opacity = "0.0";


        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }
```

The search "works" as i can only get locations in france however when i click on them the map does not update.

What is wrong here?

full version [here](https://gianlucanotaro.github.io/googlemaps-clickfunnel/)

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?  The posted code is not complete and it doesn't include any of the required HTML/CSS

Comment: If I add your `options` (with the `componentRestrictions: country: 'fr'}` to the example in the documentation, [it works (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/29xfhz6r/) for me.  What do you mean by "the map does not update"?

Comment: @geocodezip i updated my question